# jquery not working on php include file

Tags: php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Jquery Not Working On Include File.Here is My Code Sample.But in LocalHost That's Work Fine.and also i am using Bootstrap.

```
<body> 
<?php 
include('header.php');
if(UserType=="User")
{
// In This Portion Jquery Work :)
include('BProfile.php');
}
elseif(userType=="Premium")
{
//In this Portion Jquery Dose Not Work but file load properly :(
include('PProfile.php');
}
else
{
echo 'unable To Load Profile';
}
include('footer.php');
?> 
//I also Put The Jquery On Top But Dose Not Work for PProfile
<script type="..." src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Thanks and best reagards

Comment: Works in localhost? Seems confusing.

Comment: This might just be a typo in your example, but should the two UserTypes match case?

Do you get any console output in the browser when you try to load the PProfile page? Are there any errors in your server logs?

Comment: did you check in console using firebug ?

Comment: Yes checked But No error Found .

Comment: @DLowther I wrote alert function but nothing Perform.if i delete php include pprofile.php then jquery work fine .and it's also work on first if statement